# Why does the upper respiratory tract not fill with water when diving?

Tags: breathing, lungs, nose

When we swim, I know we close the some of the vestibular folds in the larynx part of the throat to hold our breath (and to avoid water from getting into the lower respiratory tract, I suppose).

I wondered, what avoids water from running into the upper respiratory tract (such as the nasal cavity and pharynx), when we e.g. dive to the bottom of a swimming pool and lie on our back on the bottom of the pool?

I've tried googling for an hour (during which I learned most of the above anatomical words), but I have not been able to find any bodily mechanic that prevents water from entering the nasal cavity... How does the body avoid this, since there is clearly two holes in our nose, which could lead to water filling our whole upper respiratory tract, if they are not closed?

Thanks!